# ng-click dispara duas vezes com um click na resolução de celular

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estou com o seguinte problema: 
  ng-click dispara duas vezes com um click na resolução de celular, quando executado no navegador não existe problema.

```
$scope.consultaItensMesa = function consultaItensMesa(mesa) {
    try {
        if (!mesa.show_item) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: $rootScope.raiz_ws + 'mesa/item',
                params: {
                    id_pedido: mesa.id_pedido
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                if (response.status !== 204) {
                    if (response.data.resultado !== undefined) {
                        mesa.itens_mesa = response.data.resultado[0].pedidoitem;
                        mesa.show_item = !mesa.show_item;
                        console.log('cai duas vezes por click na resolução dos celilares aqui!!');   
                    }
                }
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        } else {
            mesa.show_item = false;
        }

    } catch (e) {
        alertify.alert(e.message);
    }
};
```

E o HTML:

```
<div ng-init="init(1)" >
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-fab fa fa-list-ul"
        style="background-color: gray" ng-click="consultaItensMesa(mesa)"></button>
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar à pergunta a tag HTML que define o `ng-click`?

Comment: <button class="btn btn-danger btn-fab fa fa-list-ul" style="background-color: gray" ng-click="consultaItensMesa(mesa)"></button>

Comment: Agora que vi que o código estava na pergunta, só faltava formatar como código.

Comment: o erro ocorre quando uso o ngmaterial  segue o codigo **var CommerceFast = angular.module('CommerceFast', ['ionic', 'ngRoute', 'ngStorage', 'ui.utils', 'chieffancypants.loadingBar', 'ngAnimate', 'ngCookies','ngMaterial'])**

Comment: Não precisa assinar a function assim "$scope.consultaItensMesa = function consultaItensMesa(mesa) {", seria apenas "$scope.consultaItensMesa = function (mesa) {". Pode ser isso. Você acabou ficando com 2 functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha só, vi que ainda estava aberto essa questão porem eu já resolvi a algum bom tempo. O erro era que uma das bibliotecas do projeto estava com a versão errada, dei rollback e voltou a funcionar!